# How to show specific content relating to link clicked on

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am currently working on a site where my client wants a list of icons and when you click on an icon a panel slides in with the information relating to that icon.  Here is a link to the section - https://vibrantpropertyservices-u8uj.temp-dns.com/wp/services/#services.

I have the sliding panel working but I can't seem to get the relevant content to show, it just shows the first icon's info.  Here is my code:

```
    <?php
        $services_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'servicespage',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'order'   => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order'
            )
        );
    ?>
    
    
    <?php if ( $services_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $services_query->have_posts() ) : $services_query->the_post(); ?> 
            <?php $current_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
    
            <div class="icon" onclick="openNav()" data-src="content-<?php echo $current_id ?>">             
                
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">     
                <?php endif; ?>
                
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  
                
            </div>
    
            <div id="slide" class="overlay">    
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            
                <div id="content-<?php echo $current_id ?>">    
                    <div class="test">
                    
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>      
                        <?php the_content(); ?>     
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
    
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>             
</div>

/* Open when someone clicks on the span element */
            function openNav() {
              document.getElementById("slide").style.width = "100%";
            }

            /* Close when someone clicks on the "x" symbol inside the overlay */
            function closeNav() {
              document.getElementById("slide").style.width = "0%";
            }
```

I know I'm calling the id of "slide" but I don't know how to target `<div id="content-<?php echo $current_id ?>">` for each individual link?

Many thanks

Comment: Just pass the ID as a parameter to `openNav()` and `closeNav()` ...?

Comment: I've tried that, but I'm probably doing it wrong, can you tell me how?

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: ```function openNav() {
     document.getElementById("content-<?php echo $current_id ?>").style.width = "100%";
   }```

Comment: No, not there, that makes no sense. Pass the ID as parameter, when you _call_ those functions, `<div class="icon" onclick="openNav('my-own-id-here')"` And then use the passed parameter in the `getElementById` call.

Comment: This is what I've added: ```<div class="icon" onclick="openNav('content-<?php echo $current_id ?>')" data-src="content-<?php echo $current_id ?>">``` but I don't really understand how to use hte passed parameter as you say

Comment: `function openNav(id) { document.getElementById(id).style.width = "100%"; }`

Answer (score 0):

remove onclick function for both open

```
<div class="icon" data-src="content-<?php echo $current_id ?>">
```

and for close also

```
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
```

add below Jquery instead of functions

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".services-wrap .icon",function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('div.overlay').css('width:100%');
    });
    
    jQuery(document).on("click",".overlay .closebtn",function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('div.overlay').css('width:0%');
    });
```